# Doxygen "todo:86: warning: Unexpected character

Tags: doxygen

I'm having problems with Doxygen giving me warning messages such as these:

```
todo:86: warning: Unexpected character `d'
todo:86: warning: Unexpected character `o'
todo:86: warning: Unexpected character `c'
todo:86: warning: Unexpected character `/'
todo:86: warning: Unexpected character `t'
todo:86: warning: Unexpected character `e'
todo:86: warning: Unexpected character `r'
scons: *** [doc/API/html/index.html] Doxygen errors encountered, see doxygen.warn for details
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

If I look at doxygen.warn, it just contains the todo:86 lines again, which isn't really details, eh? ;)  Anyway, the characters are part of a path in my project, but they don't exist in the sources themselves.  I have no idea where the warnings are coming from, and am stuck now, as our team enforces a "no warnings, whatsoever" policy.

Any ideas on where to look for this?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using, as far as known this problem has been fixed with the current version (1.8.13). When persistent in this version please show some code that gives this problem + the changes compared to the default Doxyfile.

Comment: We are using 1.8.11 - so this was fixed?  According to git log, this was due to a \todo being in a \name block.  Is there some way to confirm that was a bug that has been fixed? Yeah, it came up again today!

Comment: see my earlier comment. Please test it with the1.8.13 and when persistent in this version please show some code that gives this problem + the changes compared to the default Doxyfile. It has been fixed at some places but maybe an odd place has been overlooked.